# Lanzar eventos con parámetros propios en pruebas

Tags: javascript, eventos, jest

Desarrollé una biblioteca en JavaScript para controlar los eventos generados por un mando de consola o joystick, y tengo una serie de tests en Jest para probar diferentes casos, pero me encuentro con un problema: no puedo simular los eventos `gamepadconnected` y `gamepaddisconnected` de forma correcta.

Mi código tiene algo como esto (simplificado):

```
const gameControl = {
  // ...
  init: function() {
    window.addEventListener('gamepadconnected', e => {
      console.log('gamepad conectado');
      if (!window.gamepads) window.gamepads = {};
      if (e.gamepad) {
        if (!window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index]) {
          window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index] = e.gamepad;
          // ...
        }
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener('gamepaddisconnected', e => {
      console.log('gamepad desconectado');
      if (e.gamepad) {
        delete window.gamepads[e.gamepad.index];
        // ...
      }
    });
  }
  // ...
};

gameControl.init();

export default gameControl;
```

Los eventos nativos `gamepadconnected` y `gamepaddisconnected` son lanzados en la ventana cuando se conecta o desconecta (respectivamente) un mando/joystick. Reciben como parámetro un evento con la propiedad `gamepad` que contiene los datos del mando/joystick conectado.

Intento lanzar los eventos de forma manual en Jest, creando un evento propio, con los parámetros que quiero (`gamepads` es un array con datos de prueba (mocks) válidos). Más o menos de este modo:

```
describe('gameControl', () => {

  // ...

  test('lanzar evento gamepadconnected', () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('gamepadconnected', {
      detail: { gamepad: gamepads[0] }
    });
    global.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  test('lanzar evento gamepaddisconnected', () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('gamepaddisconnected', {
      detail: { gamepad: gamepads[0] }
    });
    global.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  // ...

});
```

El problema viene cuando esos eventos se lanzan correctamente pero el parámetro no se pasa de forma correcta. Por ejemplo, se detecta que `gamepadconnected` se lanzó, se muestra por consola "gamepad conectado", pero luego el objeto de evento `e` no contiene la propiedad `gamepad`.

Hice un `console.log(e)` para ver qué propiedades tenía, pero me encuentro que mi parámetro no aparece por ningún lado. Esto es lo que obtengo con el `console.log`:

> CustomEvent { isTrusted: [Getter] }

¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Cómo puedo lanzar un evento con el parámetro que yo quiera para poder probar esos eventos?

Comment: Nota que un `CustomEvent` capturado tiene una propiedad `detail` tal cual cuando la declaras. Deberías acceder con `e.detail.gamepad`.

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema, mira esto https://jsfiddle.net/a3ef7kgh/1/

Comment: @takedafront pon eso como respuesta, porque es la alternativa que acabé usando. Como poco te llevarás mi positivo.

Comment: @Emeeus en ese ejemplo estás leyendo `e.detail` en lugar de `e.gamepad` que es lo que viene del evento real. Como alternativa puse en mi código que lea `e.gamepad || e.detail.gamepad`, pero eso es algo hacky (básicamente es adaptar el código para los tests). Idealmente no tendría que cambiar el código, sino lanzar el evento "nativo" (o un mock) desde los tests.

Answer (score 1):

Como dices en los comentarios, si quieres acceder directamente a `e.gamepad` sin pasar por `.detail` se puede hacer esto:

```js
const ev = new CustomEvent('gamepadconnected');

ev.gamepad = "mi valor personalizado";

document.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", (e) => {
  console.log(e.gamepad)
})


document.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

o bien añadir ambas propiedades, `detail:{gamepad}` y `gamepad`. Lo que sucede es que el constructor de [CustomEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) solo admite modificar `detail` lo demás lo hereda de `Event()`.

Comment: Útil gracias, yo lo utilizo en éste formato:
``` (
  ev = new CustomEvent('gamepadconnected')
 ).gamepad = "mi valor personalizado";

 document.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", (e) => {
  console.log(e.gamepad)
 });

 document.dispatchEvent(ev); ```  mis datos y también incluyo cancelable: detail: por si luego lo necesito.